# Recursion Theorem prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, computability, recursion, turing-machines, decidability

How to prove using the recursion theorem that the turing machine M cannot decide if the binary number 1< M>w is prime ?
Where  is the code of machine M.

Comment: what does "$1<M>w$" mean ?

Comment: @Peter, there's something missing from the second sentence, which might provide the answer to your question.

Comment: How is it that M cannot decide whether its own code is prime? M can decide whether any number is prime, no matter how large.

Comment: The correct sentence is: Where < M> is the code of machine M. And 1<M>w is the word that we want to verify if it is prime or no